# How to Tensorize loss of multiple 3D Keypoints

Tags: pytorch

I have a tensor of ground truth values of 3D points of G=[18000x3], and an output from my network of the same size O=[18000x3].

I need to compute a loss so that I basically have the square root of the distance between each 3D point, summed over all keypoints and normalized over 18000. How do I write this efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write the expression you propose using the vectorized operations provided by PyTorch. In this case

```
loss = (O - G).pow(2).sum(axis=1).sqrt().mean()
```

Check out [`pow`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.pow), [`sum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.sum), [`sqrt`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.sqrt) and [`mean`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.mean).